# How to stop displaying same posts

Tags: javascript

From the code below I am able to view my liked posts, if I press the like button of the post. But the issue is every time when I press the button to see the liked posts it's creating another same post. by the isLiked function I can like posts with heart expression and this liked post stored and when I press the like button this post appears which I liked this post but  if I press the like button again its showing another same post with the previous post.  so my question is how can I set the display function to get rid of this issue.

Here is the code

```js
   

enter code here  let posts = [];

const likedPostsId = [];


const getLikedPosts = () => {
  return posts.filter((post) => likedPostsId.includes(post.id));
};

  

const isLiked = (id) => {
  return likedPostsId?.length && likedPostsId.includes(id);
};

const addToLiked = (id) => {
  likedPostsId.push(id);

  showPosts(posts);
};

  


const switchTab = (id) => {

  if (id === "liked") {


    document.getElementById("liked").style.display = "block";

    displayLikedPosts();


  } 
};

const createPost = (post) => {
  const image = post.userImage;
  const image1 = post.image;
  const comments = post.comments;
  const div = document.createElement("article");
  div.classList.add("post");
  div.innerHTML = `
              <div class="post__header">
                <div class="post__profile">
                  <a
                    href="https://github.com/ProgrammingHero1"
                    target="_blank"
                    class="post__avatar"
                  >
                    <img src="${image}" alt="User Picture" />
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="post__user">phero</a>
                </div>

                <button class="post__more-options">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
                </button>
              </div>

              <div class="post__content">
                <div class="post__medias">
                  <img
                    class="post__media"
                    src="${image1}"
                    alt="Post Content"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="post__footer">
                <div class="post__buttons">
                
                  <button class="post__button"
                  onclick="addToLiked(${post.id})">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-heart ${isLiked(post.id) && 
                 "text-danger"}"></i>             
                  `;
                return div;
               };

  

const displayLikedPosts = () => {
  const likedPosts = getLikedPosts();
  likedPosts.forEach((post) => {
    const div = createPost(post);
    document.getElementById("liked").appendChild(div);
  });
};
```

```html
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-link active" role="button" 
                        onclick="switchTab( 'posts' )">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-link active" role="button" 
                         onclick="switchTab( 'liked' )">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-heart text-danger"></i>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-link active" role="button" 
                        onclick="switchTab( 'reported' )">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash"></i>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and the snippet within so that the code reproduces the issue you are seeing (a [mre]). Currently a syntax error is thrown because the code is incomplete, and other errors will remain because some variables are not defined (`posts`, `likedPostsId`, `createPost`, elements with ids `liked`, `posts`, and `reported`).

Comment: In `addToLiked` function, push only if it isn't already liked. i.e. `if(!isLiked(id)) likedPostsId.push(id);`  Similar for reported posts.

Comment: thne its showing the like posts repeatedly (if i liked suppose "post one" then after pressing its showing another "post one")